# Is there a way to create objects in swiftUI view based on a value gathered from a previous view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have recently started my journey into iOS development learning swift and swift UI. I keep running into issues when it comes to app architecture. The problem i am trying to solve is this: Let's say I have an app where the user first selects a number and then presses next. The user selected number is supposed to represent the number of text fields that appear on the next view. For example, if the user selects 3 then 3 text fields will appear on the next view but if the user selects 5 then 5 texts fields will appear. Is the solution to just have a view for each case? Or is there some way to dynamically add objects to a view based on the user input. Can anyone explain how they would handle a case like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views can get passed parameters (including in `NavigationLink`) that can determine what they look like. Here's a simple example with what you described:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var numberOfFields = 3
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Stepper(value: $numberOfFields, in: 1...5) {
                    Text("Number of fields: \(numberOfFields)")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(numberOfFields: numberOfFields)) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var numberOfFields : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<numberOfFields) { index in
                TextField("", text: .constant("Field \(index + 1)"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how `numberOfFields` is stored as `@State` in the parent view and then passed to the child view dynamically.

---

In general, it would probably be a good idea to visit some SwiftUI tutorials as this type of thing will be covered by most of them. Apple's official tutorials are here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

Another very popular resource is Hacking With Swift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui

---

**Update, based on comments**:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var numberOfFields = 3
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Stepper(value: $numberOfFields, in: 1...5) {
                    Text("Number of fields: \(numberOfFields)")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(textInputs: Array(repeating: "test", count: numberOfFields))) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct Model : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text : String
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var strings : [Model] = []
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var textInputs : [String]
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(viewModel.strings.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,text) in
                TextField("", text: $viewModel.strings[index].text)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            viewModel.strings = textInputs.map { Model(text: $0) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this was super helpful. Will definitely be checking out those resources. One more question, no worries if you cant help. Now i want to store the user text inputs into an array. Would i do this inside of the TextField declaration inside of the forEach loop? Or somewhere else? Thanks again

Comment: It's pretty hard to say what the best way to do this is without having any information about how this is going to get used. I updated my answer with one possible way to do it. I added `Model` because for the bindings and `ForEach` to work smoothly, I needed unique IDs for the strings. If these answers work for you, you can accept them by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: Awesome this should work great. Hope to be as proficient in swift as you are one day! Thanks for all the help.